# Meteor JS - Launch function after every templates are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, meteor

using Meteor JS, I would like to start a basic jQuery function (wich will resize some elements) everytime a template is loaded.
I tried to call this function inside Meteor.startup() but this doesn't work.
I also tried to launch my function on Router.onBeforeAction() with no more results (im using ironRouter).

Is there any way to do something like :

```
Template.someTemplate.created = function(){
  myUpdateFunction(); 
};
```

But instead of loading this on a specific template, i would like to automaticly load this on every templates in my app.

Is there a way to simply achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will log every Template's name after it is created:

```
Template.prototype.created = function() {
    console.log(this.view.name);
}
```

However your jquery will require the template to be rendered, so this will probably work better:

```
Template.prototype.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.view.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve it by wrapping [`Blaze._fireCallbacks`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/blaze/view.js#L274) :

```
Blaze._fireCallbacks = (function(_fireCallbacks) {
  return function(view, which) {
    _fireCallbacks(view, which)
    if(which === 'rendered') {
      //Add your logic here
    }
  }
})(Blaze._fireCallbacks)
```

Might not be the most simple solution. See a demo [on this pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/T9oHsAuNBb9EnHvNd).